# PhantomJS: Cannot have setup/teardown in describe

Tags: javascript, jenkins, phantomjs, mocha.js, chai

**Has anyone ever seen this before and have any idea what it means?**

```
14:13:43 PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR
14:13:43   Error: Cannot have setup/teardown in describe for: athena-vertical-expanding-carousel
14:13:43   at /home/jenkins/workspace/Shared_GD_Build/frontend/test/js/test.js:40
```

I have a very similar set of tests and they are working but maybe there is something wrong with these:

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "underscore",
  "common/athena/vertical-expanding-carousel"
], function ($, _, AthVertExpandingCarousel) {

  describe("common/", function () {
describe("athena/", function () {

  describe("athena-vertical-expanding-carousel", function () {
    var $fixture,
      carousel,
      sandbox;

    beforeEach(function () {
      sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
      $fixture = $([
        "<div id='vert-carousel-test-outer' class='generic_container'>",
        "<div id='vert-carousel-test' class='js-vertCarouselMainContainer" +
        " vertCarouselMainContainer carousel'>",
        "  <ol class='js-carousel-items'>",
        "    <li class='selected'>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "    <li>",
        "      <div><a href='#'><img data-lazy='/static-mock/empty.png' /></a></div>",
        "    </li>",
        "  </ol>",
        "</div>",
        "<div class='paginator-container' id='paginator-container'>",
        " <div class='js-up-down-controls'>",
        "   <div class='js-up-controls'>",
        "   </div>",
        "   <div class='js-down-controls'>",
        "   </div>",
        " </div>",
        "</div>",
        "</div>"
      ].join("\n")).appendTo($("#fixtures-visible"));
    });

    afterEach(function () {
      $fixture.remove();
      sandbox.restore();
      if (carousel) {
        carousel.remove();
      }
    });

    describe("base case", function () {

      it("should not have any new classes indicating initialization if a bad " +
        "selector is sent", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($("nada"),
          {maxRows: 5});

        expect($upDownControls).to
          .not
            .have.$class("atTop").and
            .have.$class("atBottom");
      });

      it("should have class of atTop and not atBottom in controlls after " +
        "being initialized", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});

        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.have.$class("atTop").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atBottom");
      });

      // We may add an init option to start with more than one row,
      // but for now we start at 1 row
      it("should have class of vertPages1 after being initialized", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});

        expect($vertCarouselContainer)
          .to.have.$class("vertPages1");
      });

      it("should have class of vertPages2 and lose the the atTop class " +
        "in controls after init and a downclick", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");
        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click();

        expect($vertCarouselContainer)
          .to.have.$class("vertPages2").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atTop");
      });

      it("should have class of atTop and not the atBottom class " +
        "after init and an upCLick", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-up-controls").click();

        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.have.$class("atTop").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atBottom");
      });

      it("should have class of vertPages1 and data value of 1 for vertCarSize " +
        "after init and an upCLick", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-up-controls").click();

        expect($vertCarouselContainer)
          .to.have.$class("vertPages1");
      });

      it("should have class of vertPages3 and data value of 3 for vertCarSize " +
        "after init and TWO downClicks", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();

        expect($vertCarouselContainer)
          .to.have.$class("vertPages3");
      });

      it("should have class of atTop and not atBottom after being initialized, " +
        "a downclick and an upclick", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 5});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click();
        $upDownControls.find(".js-up-controls").click();

        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.have.$class("atTop").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atBottom");
      });

      it("should have class of atBottom and not atTop after being initialized w " +
        "max of 3 rows and two downclicks", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 3});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();

        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.have.$class("atBottom").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atTop");
      });

      it("should have class of atBottom and not atTop after being initialized w max " +
        "of 3 rows and three downclicks", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer,
          {maxRows: 3});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();

        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click(); // one too many
        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.have.$class("atBottom").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atTop");
      });

      it("should have class of atBottom and not atTop after being initialized w NO MAX " +
        "rows and three downclicks but not at two downclicks", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer, {});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();

        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.not.have.$class("atBottom").and
          .to.have.$class("atTop");

        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click();
        expect($upDownControls)
          .to.have.$class("atBottom").and
          .to.not.have.$class("atTop");
      });

      it("should have data value of vertCarSize=4 after being initialized w NO MAX " +
        "rows and three downclicks but only 3 after two down clicks", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer, {});
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();

        expect($vertCarouselContainer).to.have.$class("vertPages3");

        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click();
        expect($vertCarouselContainer)
          .to.have.$class("vertPages4");
      });

      it("should have data value of vertCarSize=4 after being initialized w NO SECOND PARAM " +
        "rows and 3 downclicks but only three after 2 down clicks", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer);
        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();

        expect($vertCarouselContainer).to.have.$class("vertPages3");

        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click();
        expect($vertCarouselContainer)
          .to.have.$class("vertPages4");
      });

      it("should have startTransition and then transitionComplete as a class after leaving " +
        "atTop", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        sandbox.useFakeTimers();

        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer, {});

        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click();

        expect($upDownControls).to.have.$class("startTransition");
        expect($upDownControls).to.not.have.$class("transitionComplete");
        expect($upDownControls).to.not.have.$class("atTop");

        sandbox.clock.tick(1750);

        expect($upDownControls).to.have.$class("transitionComplete");
        expect($upDownControls).to.not.have.$class("startTransition");

      });

      it("should have startTransition and then transitionComplete as a class after leaving " +
        "atBottom", function () {
        var $vertCarouselContainer = $("#vert-carousel-test"),
          $upDownControls = $vertCarouselContainer.parent().find(".js-up-down-controls");

        sandbox.useFakeTimers();
        $vertCarouselContainer.addClass("js-vertical-carousel-main-container");

        carousel = AthVertExpandingCarousel.init($vertCarouselContainer, {maxRows: 2});

        $upDownControls.find(".js-down-controls").click().click();
        sandbox.clock.tick(1750);

        $upDownControls.find(".js-up-controls").click();

        expect($upDownControls).to.have.$class("startTransition");
        expect($upDownControls).to.not.have.$class("transitionComplete");
        expect($upDownControls).to.not.have.$class("atBottom");

        sandbox.clock.tick(1750);

        expect($upDownControls).to.have.$class("transitionComplete");
        expect($upDownControls).to.not.have.$class("startTransition");

      });
    });
  });
});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker helped me realize that I used the same "describe" string in two different .spec files:

```
describe("athena-vertical-expanding-carousel", function () {
```

I had no idea that phantom, jenkins, etc can be configured to be so strict to prevent duplicate labels but it makes sense.

I was unable to find stackoverflow questions to this exact error so I hope this will help some one ..  .